# sudo -k vs. sudo -K

Tags: linux, unix

I know what the man page has to say about the -K and -k :

> ‑K
>
> The ‑K (sure kill) option is like ‑k except that it removes the user's
>   cached credentials entirely and may not be used in conjunction with a
>   command or other option. This option does not require a password. Not
>   all security policies support credential caching.
>
> ‑k[command]
>
> When used alone, the ‑k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the user's
>   cached credentials. The next time sudo is run a password will be
>   required. This option does not require a password and was added to
>   allow a user to revoke sudo permissions from a .logout file. Not all
>   security policies support credential caching. When used in conjunction
>   with a command or an option that may require a password, the ‑k option
>   will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached credentials. As a result,
>   sudo will prompt for a password (if one is required by the security
>   policy) and will not update the user's cached credentials.

So if there is no need to use a command in conjunction with these options, am i correct in assuming K is always the better option to use rather that k?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -K` and `sudo -k`, without a command, do the same thing: they invalidate the user's cached credentials.

`sudo -k command ...` is different: it *ignores* the user's cached credentials for the current command, but doesn't invalidate them.

Use `-k` with a command when you want to run a single command without either using or clobbering your cached credentials.  (I'm actually not sure why you'd want to do that, but the capability is there.)

Use either `sudo -k` or `sudo -K` if you want to clobber your cached credentials.

Summary:

```
sudo -k           # clobbers cached credentials
sudo -K           # clobbers cached credentials
sudo -k command   # ignores cached credentials
sudo -K command   # invalid
```